# webmatrix pass ID to display code

Tags: c#, webmatrix

I am currently going nuts making a page to display the contents when an ID is passsed to it.
The code i have can be found below

```
 @{  
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Home";
var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
 var PageID  = UrlData[0]; 
 if (PageID.IsEmpty()) { 
     PageID = "1";
 } 
var pages = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM PAGES WHERE Id = @0",PageID);
```

}

```
        <div class="productInfo">
            <h3>@pages.Body</h3>
            </div>
```

Basically what i am trying to get it to do is when you enter the url default/1 that the body of the page which has an id of 1 will appear and that if no querystring is given it will default to ID 1

When i run this i get an error with the line

#### @pages.Body

stating Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

the URL passed is http://localhost:20756/Default/1 and there is a page with an ID of 1 in the system

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code as-is. Double check to make sure you are looking at the right database, and that it definitely has the relevant entry in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the exception in other words:

your runtime said:

> "you gave me a query that did not
>   return anything, but want me to access
>   some data on that result ... errm ...
>   that's not going to happen"

if this code runs in your default.cshtml, try removing "Default/" from your url ...

note that `PageID.IsEmpty()` is not evaluating to `true` since `UrlData[0]` will probably contain `"Default"`

Comment: Hello DarkSquirrel and Mike Brind thank you for your help turns out the code was correct and that i had messed up and deleted the page record (hence why it received a NULL value )